# NoSuchMethodError on Google Appengine - Is there a good way to track these down and fix them

Tags: java, google-app-engine

My approach for fixing "NoSuchMethodError" problems on appengine is very trial and error, is that the best way, or does a better way exist?

**Error:**
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.decrypt(Lsun/security/ssl/CipherBox;)V

I am guessing because "MAC" has been added, Java 1.7.0_25 has decrypt(MAC, CipherBox)

**General solution**
 Has anyone come up with a good system for tracking down NoSuchMethodError errors and 
fixing them. I keep getting JAR version issues. They happen a lot and cause so many problems. Everything compiles fine in eclipse and then I deploy and along comes another "NoSuchMethodError". Is there some way to catch these, at compile time, or any rule of thumb that works well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These errors will not appear at compile time, because it is not your code who's calling the missing method. It is some of your dependencies calling for one of its subdependencies method, which doesn't exist.

These errors ocurr mostly at runtime, and are indeed hard to find.

The best aproach is using some dependency management system (like Maven), that will use the correct dependencies, and subdependencies. JUnit test could also help finding this issues, depending on coverage of the tests.

Comment: Maven is no 5min learning curve ... guess I need to dig in and take the time to get to grips with it. Thanks.